# ImageMagick move watermark from top left to bottom right?

Tags: php, imagemagick

I've got this working adding a watermark onto my image at the top left, How can i change it so it adds in the bottom right?

Here is my current code:

```
    $watermark = new Imagick();
    $watermark->readImage("images/watermark_boxart.png");
    $im->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 3, 3);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the watermark at (3,3). You need to set it in the bottom right by placing these numbers accordingly.

> Methodology:
>
> 1. Calculate width and height on $im [$im_height, $im_width]
> 2. Calculate width and height of $watermerk [$wm_height, $wm_width]
> 3. Find the coordinates to place the watermark at via calculation of differences in dimensions
> 4. Create composite with calculated locations

Code:

```
$im_d = $im->getImageGeometry(); 
$im_w = $im_d['width']; 
$im_h = $im_d['height']; 


$watermark = new Imagick();
$watermark->readImage("images/watermark_boxart.png");
$watermark_d = $watermark->getImageGeometry();
$watermark_w = $watermark_d['width'];
$watermark_h = $watermark_d['height'];

$margin = 3;
$x_loc = $im_w - $watermark_w - $margin;
$y_loc = $im_h - $watermark_h - $margin; 

$im->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $x_loc, $y_loc);
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to be working. Appreciate you explaining it as well.